# Debian Jessie Nvidia proprietary drivers and screen brightness buttons

Tags: debian, osx, nvidia, brightness, backlight

How do you make Mac OS X screen brightness work when using Debian Jessie 8 and Nvidia proprietary drivers?

There are a lot of answers floating around about editing the config file adding some options but none of those worked for me.

How can I get the back light keys to work?

Comment: sorry but I can't get what was your problem.

Comment: You seem to have posted an answer without its question. What is this a solution to? Please edit your question post to add that missing question (describe the problem), and post an answer to provide your actual answer (this command, and explain what this command does and why it solves the problem).

Comment: The solution is to do this from a terminal:

    # setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0

you can read about it [here][1]

Hopefully it saves someone some time and headache.


  [1]: http://iocrunch.com/2014/08/nvidia-backlight-in-linux-on-macbookpro-113/

Comment: Fair enough, and thank you. I've reopened this so you can answer it yourself, but please [edit] the question to make it clearer. What do you mean by "OSX screen brightness when using Debian"? Do you mean the buttons that change the brightness level? Why do you mention backlight in the end then? That has nothing to do with screen brightness.

Comment: my apologies, it was a typo. You are right that I was referring to using the apple keyboard buttons F1 and F2 to control the screen brightness.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to shared this answer because I read a lot of different reports of how to make your mac os x keyboard control the brightness of your display.

use this command at a terminal: #

```
setpci -v -H1 -s 00:01.00 BRIDGE_CONTROL=0
```

you might have to be root. Check out this [full article](http://iocrunch.com/2014/08/nvidia-backlight-in-linux-on-macbookpro-113/), it's what worked for me.